# CodeIgniter URL not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

`enter code here`I got this code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projFolder

### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

# If your default controller is something other than
# "welcome" you should probably change this
RewriteRule ^(mycontrol(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ /  [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce www
# If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
# the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

# Enforce NO www
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

###

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

My project is in /var/www/projFolder -> the structure in that folder is

```
/application
/system
/user_guide
.htaccess
index.php
```

i changed $route['default_controller'] = "mycontrol"; in the config routes.php file.
if i type the url localhost/projFolder/ it load the default mycontrol.php controller and the index function from that controller. If i go localhost/projFolder/myFunction -> meaning that i want to load myFunction from the default controller it gives me "The requested URL  was not found on this server." Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

open your `config/routes.php` file

add this line:

```
$route['mycontrol/(:any)'] = "mycontrol/index";
```

then i never used a so huge `.htaccess` with codeigniter, i always use this and it works great:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projFolder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

to remove index.php you have to use htaccess and change in `config/config.php`:

```
$config['index_page']='';
```

Comment: the problem is that i have to write localhost/projFolder/index.php/ to load controllers and functions from controllers. I want to remove index.php from the url so it works like localhost/projFolder/mycontrol

Comment: @LachezarRaychev ok so check my answer is updated now, you have problems in re-writing urls so it could be htaccess or config file, did you tryed my htaccess?

Comment: Yes... sadly it is not working :( 5 hours on this sh*T already

Comment: @LachezarRaychev but pls google how to remove index.php from url in codeigniter and report errors here

Comment: i put it on virtual host and it was good with the official code igniter .htaccess

Comment: ok @LachezarRaychev so you fixed that now ? :) nice , the documentation has always what you need ;)

Answer (score 1):

edit you .htaccess fiel to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although `mycontrol` is the default controller, it's not going to work, because it expects to find a `controller` called `myFunction` when you type `localhost/projFolder/myFunction`. If you want to access `myfunction` try to type `localhost/projFolder/mycontrol/myFunction`. Using this approach you will call the controller and ask for a specific function.